# Suppose $T^{m}=T^{n}$ for some positive integers $m \neq n .$ Find conditions on $T, m$ and $n$ such that $T^{2}=T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Problem**: Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbf{C}$ and let $T: V \mapsto V$ denote a linear map satisfying $T^{m}=T^{n}$ for some positive integers $m \neq n .$ Find conditions on $T, m$ and $n$ such that $T^{2}=T$.

**Attempt**:
Let $A$ be the matrix representing $T$ with respect to any base. Then $A^{m}=A^{n}$. If $A=P R P^{-1}$ and $R$ is the Jordan matrix corresponding to $A$, then $R^{m}=R^{n} .$

I have no idea how to continue, I can't see if what I've done will even lead me anywhere. Any help?
Surely $ A=0,I $ are among the conditions but how to find the rest of them?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If $A$ is a Jordan block. Then when does $A^m=A^n$?

Comment: Note sure... but if we denote $  J_r(\lambda)$ a jordan block of size $ r $ then we'd want $ J_r(\lambda)^2 = J_r(\lambda) $ to have the condition that $ T^2 = T $

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like $A^m=A^n$ iff the diagonal element (the eigenvalue) is $0$  (in which case $A^m=0$) or the size  of $A$ is $1$ and $A$ is  a root of $1$ or $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T^2=T$, the minimal polynomial $\mu_T(x)$ of $T$ divides $x(x-1)$. Hence $\mu_T$ splits in linear factors and $T$ is diagonalizable with only $0$ or $1$ on the diagonal.

Conversely, if $T$ is diagonalizable with only $0$ or $1$ on the diagonal, then $T^m = T^n$ for any $m,n \in \mathbb N$.

*Hence $T$ diagonalizable with only $0$ or $1$ on the diagonal is the condition we're looking for.*